# PHP socket client to connect to multiple remote servers to merge output

Tags: php, sockets, client

I have multiple TCP servers which provide an output stream in the same format.  I'm trying to write a client in PHP which will connect to each of these and will accept the data that they stream to it.  My intention is to combine these multiple streams into one stream for later processing.

I've written a TCP server before where a master socket accepts connections and when a new client connects this creates a new socket.  This new socket is added to an array of sockets and sockect_select is then used to detect which socket to read.

I'd like to adopt a similar approach although I know that I can't have a master socket what I need to do is to create one socket per client-server connection.

The code that I have written allows me to build this list of sockets but when I run it the code tells me that the socket has changed but at this point I'm stuck.

How do I know which socket to read from?

```
$client = new Client();

// start the server
$client->connect('1.2.3.4', 50000);
$client->connect('5.6.7.8', 50001);

public function connect($ip, $port) {
    // Connect to remote server

    try{
        // Create socket
        if ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
            $this->log("Socket created");
        } else {
            $this->log("Error creating socket");
        }

        // Connect to server
        if (socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port)){
            $this->log("Socket connected to $ip:$port");

            $this->sockets[]=$socket;
            $this->onConnected();
        } else {
            $this->log("Error connecting to server");
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        $this->log("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function onConnected() {
    foreach ($this->sockets as $socket) {
        socket_set_nonblock($socket);
    }

    // Add the socket that we're monitoring to an array
    $streams=$this->sockets;

    $write=null;
    $except=null;

    // Look for data on the socket
    while (socket_select($streams, $write, $except, 0, 0) !== FALSE) {
        echo ("Socket changed");

        // The following code doesn't read from the socket
        if (in_array($this->sockets, $streams)) {
            // Read up to 8K of data into the buffer
            while (@socket_recv($this->sockets, $buffer, 8192, 0)) {
                echo ("LINE: " . $buffer);
            }
        }

        $streams=$this->sockets;
    }
}
```

What I would expect to see is lines of data from each of the server's output as they come in but instead, I just see a lot of "Socket changed"

so, how do I determine which socket has changed so that I can read from it?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the PHP manual on [socket_select()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), it says:

> **Warning** On exit, the arrays are modified to indicate which socket resource actually changed status.

And also:

> On success socket_select() returns the number of socket resources
>   contained in the modified arrays, which may be zero if the timeout
>   expires before anything interesting happens.

So anything left in `$streams`, which are your sockets, is a changed socket.

Knowing this, your code below makes no sense:

```
if (in_array($this->sockets, $streams)) {
```

because `$this->sockets` contains all your sockets and `$streams` only those that have changed. In other words, this will always be `false`. What you can do is:

```
public function onConnected() {
    // Add the socket that we're monitoring to an array
    $streams = $this->sockets;
    $write   = null;
    $except  = null;
    // Look for data on the socket
    while (socket_select($streams, $write, $except, 0, 0) !== FALSE) {
        echo ("Socket changed");
        // The following code does read from the sockets that have changed
        foreach ($streams as $stream) {
            while (socket_recv($stream, $buffer, 8192, 0)) {
                echo ("LINE: " . $buffer);
            }
        }            
        // Look at all streams again
        $streams = $this->sockets;
    }
    // The following code does read from the sockets that have changed
    foreach ($streams as $stream) {
        while (socket_recv($stream, $buffer, 8192, 0)) {
            echo ("LINE: " . $buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

This should read from the changed sockets, assuming that the rest of the code works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It almost works in that it only seems to detect the first changed socket, it doesn't notice the other sockets that have changed so $streams only ever contains one socket :-(  They are set to non-blocking so I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: @PhilipLee I have expanded the code in my answer to include the outer while loop. Notice how I reset the `$streams` every time inside this while loop. Please note that my answer is only intended to solve the problem you mentioned in your question. There might still be other problem with your code.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the update but I'm still seeing the same result as before - only one changed socket is being detected.  There's a second copy of the block of code preceeded with // The following code does read from the sockets that have changed.  Presumably that NOT meant to be there ?